# Why is this javascript validation not working for the selectlist

Tags: javascript

The javascript should be checking to see if the user didn't select anything in a select list if the value is the first option which is "Please choose a seminar". It appears to just ignore the script.

```
<apex:page controller="vfCnt_chooseSeminar" >

<apex:form > 

<apex:PageBlock title="Choose Your Preferred Seminar(s) for {!progName}">

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveItem}" value="Next"/>
                <apex:commandButton onclick="validateFunction('{!$Component.first}')" action="{!cancelAction}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <h1>First Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList id="first" value="{!semName1}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
            <p />
                    <h1>Second Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList id="second" value="{!semName2}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
             <p />
                    <h1>Third Preference:</h1><p />
                   <apex:selectList id="third" value="{!semName3}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                   </apex:selectList>
</apex:PageBlock>
      </apex:form>

     <!-- Java script starts Here -->
  <script>
   function validateFunction(first){
       var inputAmount = document.getElementById(first).value;
         if(inputAmount == 'Please Choose a Seminar'){
            alert('Please enter seminar1');
         } 
  }
  </script> 
 <!-- java script ends here -->  

</apex:page>
```

Comment: or may be your VF component inside other component that why you are not able to access check the doc for nested component https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm

Comment: I pasted the <script> inside the apex:form tag and tried it, no go. I then put it inside the apex:pageblock. Still nothing. Any other suggestions?  If the first option is  'Please Choose a Seminar' do I use inputAmount == 'Please Choose a Seminar' or inputAmount == Null because they never chose anything?

Comment: Apex N-u-b.... check Sergey Utko's Answer that will help you. same mentioned here as well [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can not just access the selected value using `.value` notation of the object. 
You have to access the `options` first and then get the selected option like this:

```javascript
var inputAmount = document.getElementById(first).value;
var val = inputAmount.options[inputAmount.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: I added your fix and then I added an alert ("Hi") in function validateFunction. It doesn't seem like the function is being called. How to get it to run? I have a feeling that then your fix will make it work.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b I think your function is being called, but you should to check the `{!$Component.first}` parameter. You are trying to access the `first` element before it was initialized in visualforce code (the button is rendered before the `first`element and is trying to access the `first` elements ID, that is actually not exists for that point of time). I would try to place the button after the `first` element and try the function again.

Comment: I tried it. Still no sign of life. Right now if I can only get the alert to show Hi that would convince me that it's running. Do I need to include something like jquery files or something?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Ok I think I know what the problem is. In the `commandButton` code you have no `rerender` attribute. Without it after click on the button the page will be reloaded. That is the problem. Add a `rerender` attribute and it will work: `<apex:commandButton onclick="validateFunction('{!$Component.first}')" action="{!cancelAction}" value="Cancel" reRender="none"/>` Alternatively you can add `return false;` to the `onclick`: `onclick="validateFunction('{!$Component.first}'); return false;"`

Comment: Neither works (added both). FYI, the page redirects to another vf page after an update.  But why should this matter, shouldn't the script run before anything is done so it can cancel further actions if the logic dictates?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b If you want to display something to the user before redirecting him to another page you better use another construct: click on the button > display the popup-message > wait for the user action (i.e. click on the OK button) > now redirect to another page. Do not mix the JS logic and Apex.

Comment: Ok. btw you and sfdcweb are very patient with guys like us. It is appreciated. Many thanks for all your advice.

Comment: @ApexN-u-b You are welcome!